# problem with exponents (like a³)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I use French keyboard setting, when I try to write "a^3" I should click the button "^" and then the space button to get "a^3", if I do not click space I get "a³", which is quite annoying while working on long latex document.

Do you have any solution for this ? so I don't have to click the space button each time I click "^".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply go to

1. System Settings
2. Keyboard
3. Text Entry (under the tab "Typing")
4. Add input source (the plus)
5. choose "French (eliminate dead keys)"

This is for Ubuntu 14.04 so some of the names may vary. But all you have to do is eliminate dead keys.